# The article for the word 'metadata'

Tags: articles

Whil writing an academic paper, I would like to use the word 'metadata' to describe a sort of a list entry. In this context, I feel like using 'a' before the word 'metadata' as it looks like it clarifies the point that it is a 'single' entry, but the dictionary says the word 'metadata' should be used without an article. Can I use 'a' before the word 'metadata' in my usage, or is there any other options that I can alternatively choose?

Comment: A piece of metadata.

Comment: I can't imagine any reasonable context were "a metadata" would be used, with "metadata" functioning as a noun.  It is pretty much always a mass noun.  If you need to refer to an element of the metadata, refer to an element of the metadata.

Answer (score 1):

*Data* is etymologically plural, and normally treated as a mass noun (*some data* is common, **a data* not generally accepted). *The data* can be read as *all the data* (roughly).

So you would normally use *an item of data*, *a piece of data*, or in some contexts *a data point*. I see no reason for the *meta-* prefix to change this.

You could even back form [*metadatum*](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/metadatum) if you were so inclined. I wouldn't. *Datum* isn't common enough in this context (it's more common as a reference position in engineering or navigation). Actually that link (wiktionary) calls it a singular form rather than a back-formation, but there's discussion on the entry's talk page suggesting that back-formation is likely. It doesn't show up in any more authoritative dictionaries online.